# Repeat function to find descriptive statistics for several data columns

Tags: r, function, sapply

Trying to do a repeat function and descriptive statistics. The line below

```
print (table <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(50:100,10,rep=TRUE))))
```

generates the table in the image.[image: simple data table]

I would like to do some descriptive statistics on columns X1 and X4, using the coding below.

```
GenStats <- function(x){
  newMatrix <- matrix (1:8, nrow = 1)
  colnames(newMatrix) <- c("Mean", "Median", "Maximum", "Variance", "Minimum", "Skewness",
                           "Kurtosis", "Std.Dev")
  rownames(newMatrix) <- "Key Statistics" 
  newMatrix[1,] <- c(mean(x), median(x), max(x), var(x), min(x),
                     skewness(x), kurtosis(x), sd(x))
  newMatrix
}
```

I can get this to work for 1 sample e.g.

x<- table$X1, with GenStats(x)

My question then - how do I look at two samples (treated independently) e.g. X1 and X4?

I tried this -

```
x <- c("table$X1", "table$X4")
```

but that didn't work.

I tried then using sapply e.g.

```
sapply(x, function(x) {
  + (x[, c(mean, median, sd)])
  + })
```

but got an unexpected '}' in the error message.

As always, would appreciate it if someone could guide me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Whats `x` in your `sapply()`?  You have `function(y)` but no `y` is used. Also, what is `y`? (the first one in `sapply`)

Comment: Apols Sotos, have corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this resolve your problem?

```
library(dplyr)
output <- sapply(table %>% select(X1,X4), FUN = GenStats)
rownames(output) <- c("Mean", "Median", "Maximum", "Variance", "Minimum", "Skewness",
                      "Kurtosis", "Std.Dev")
output
                  X1           X4
Mean      78.9000000  76.10000000
Median    84.0000000  74.50000000
Maximum   96.0000000  95.00000000
Variance 286.9888889 222.54444444
Minimum   52.0000000  53.00000000
Skewness  -0.4325578  -0.03126238
Kurtosis  -1.5714491  -1.59510245
Std.Dev   16.9407464  14.91792360
```

Edit: You can replace X1 and X4 in the fist line to apply the function on the columns you want

Comment: Don't use `apply` on data frames. `apply` coerces to matrix before any operations thus making it inefficient. You should only use it if the input is a matrix. For data frames, `sapply` or `lapply` are better

Comment: I didn't know all that @Sotos, thanks for this knowledge. Therefore, I edited with sapply

Comment: MonJeanJean, what library is required to enable me to use %>%>.?  ...could not find function...

Comment: Sorry, it is `dplyr`

Comment: Why load `dplyr` just for selecting the columns? Why not just `sapply(table[c('X1', 'X4')], GenStats)`

Comment: Force of the habits

Answer (score 1):

You could use `describe` from `psych` library:

```
library(psych)
describe(table[,c("X1", "X4")])
```

Output:

```
   vars  n mean    sd median trimmed   mad min max range skew kurtosis   se
X1    1 10 67.2 16.61   61.5   65.25 14.83  50 100    50 0.64    -1.08 5.25
X4    2 10 72.6 15.92   73.0   72.62 22.24  53  92    39 0.00    -1.90 5.03
```

**OR: with your own function**
With `lapply` notice `skewness` is changed to skew and `kurtosis` to `kurtosi`

```
library(psych)
GenStats <- function(x){
    newMatrix <- matrix (1:8, nrow = 1)
    colnames(newMatrix) <- c("Mean", "Median", "Maximum", "Variance", "Minimum", "Skewness",
                             "Kurtosis", "Std.Dev")
    rownames(newMatrix) <- "Key Statistics" 
    newMatrix[1,] <- c(mean(x), median(x), max(x), var(x), min(x),
                       skew(x), kurtosi(x), sd(x))
    newMatrix
}

lapply(table[,c(1,4)], GenStats)
```

Output:

```
$X1
               Mean Median Maximum Variance Minimum  Skewness  Kurtosis  Std.Dev
Key Statistics 67.2   61.5     100 275.9556      50 0.6432985 -1.079559 16.61191

$X4
               Mean Median Maximum Variance Minimum    Skewness Kurtosis  Std.Dev
Key Statistics 72.6     73      92 253.3778      53 0.004540284 -1.90361 15.91784
```